# Does cache build up on a thin client when you RDP into a host?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, cache

Co worker keeps trying to tell me that in order to fix issues on a remote host such as web browser slowness, you need to clear the cache on the thin client itself.
How does the internet options cache have any relevance on the thin client when youre browsing the web on a remote desktop connection?

Comment: It doesn’t. Silliest thing ever.

Comment: Anything than could potentially be fixed on the thin client itself would be related to connecting to the remote host. For example, clearing cached DNS results (which should happen automatically anyhow). However, if its anything to do with the remote host (ie, anything you could do with direct access to the machine itself), then theres nothing you could do on the thin client itself that would fix the issue. So, no, it has no relevance whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

**Cache is like soap. It's self-cleaning.**

People who advise to clear caches on a regular basis don't understand how they work.

Ignore them.

Comment: You're forgetting the corollary: People who think they know about caches and give this kind of advice don't actually know much about how caches work.